# Can any handballs get carded when not in the box?

Tags: football, officiating

If a handball by a defender while the ball is in the box, I can understand being carded.

I'm wondering if there is a handball so egregious when outside the box that it can get a card, yellow or red.

Comment: Any unsportsmanlike handball is to be cautioned (e.g. if they do it on purpose). And a goalie handling the ball outside of his box will see a card as well. Denying goal scoring opportunities is a straight red card. Is there a specific situation you want elaborated? Right now the full answer would be pretty long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course they can, the most obvious example being if the handball is used to deny an obvious goalscoring opportunity.

Comment: I think question is about other cases (the rules say that the yellow card can be given for especially cynical handball even if they don't prevent a goal). Anyway, do you have any example in which this happens outside the box?

Comment: Sure. Pass is made, tackle misses, defender sticks out their hand to knock it away. Or even more straightforward, goalkeeper outside the box touches with hands to stop the shot. Plenty of videos where it happens at pro level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they might get booked for it as well. For instance, if they interrupt in between, unnecessarily or as it has already been commented, even a goalkeeper can get booked if he is handling the ball outside of his box.